# return object array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I currently have a file which i need to read that has the following information

> $deployTargets=@{
>       "1"=@{"WhiteList" = @("Dave", "Andrew")}; 
>       "2"=@{"BlackList" = @("Rita", "Sanjay")}; 
>       };

I am trying to write a powershell script that will return this information from the ps1 file if the deploy target = 1 and return the whitelist.

any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Simon

Answer (score 1):

FTR, I downvoted your question, because it doesn't show any effort of your own. But since the question is simple and clear enough I'm answering anyway.

Your data structure is hashtable with nested hashtables. In JSON notation the structure looks like this:

```
PS C:\> $deployTargets | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "2":  {
              "BlackList":  [
                                "Rita",
                                "Sanjay"
                            ]
          },
    "1":  {
              "WhiteList":  [
                                "Dave",
                                "Andrew"
                            ]
          }
}
```

A hashtable (basically a dictionary) is a list of key/value pairs. The elements of a hashtable can be accessed by their respective key like this:

```
$hashtable[key]
```

or like this:

```
$hashtable.key
```

So you can access the desired information like this:

```
$deployTargets['1'][Whitelist]
```

or like this:

```
$deployTargets.'1'.Whitelist
```

The quotes around the first key (`'1'`) are required, because that key is the string `'1'`, not the integer `1`.

Comment: it didnt show any effort becsause everything i had tried was not giving me what i want...  

however before seeing your response i found what i needed through perseverance...  and by using `$deploytargets.($code).('whitelist') `

Comment: @SimonPrice "Showing an effort" means you need to show what you already tried, what results that yielded, and how those results were different from your expectations. It's also common courtesy towards the people you're asking for help, so that they don't need to go through all the motions again that you already went through.